# "Linking" or forwarding sub-loggers in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I've been following (what I believe) is the correct practice WRT to logging when creating library functions.  I do the following to create a sub-logger within a given function of my library:

my_lib.py

```
import logging
def my_func():
    log = logging.getLogger('my_lib.my_func')
    log.debug("You've just called my_lib.my_func!")
```

In my main program, I get a logger "for free" from the project's library.  This Project logger has handlers and formatters already set up.  The output format is fancy and is the preferred way to log for this project.

By default, `my_lib`'s loggers inherit the logging level (`logging.INFO`) of the main (`logging.getLogger('')`) logger , therefore the `log.debug()` message isn't seen by default when the program is run.

If I want to see the logging message from my library, I can configure the `my_lib.my_func` logger like so from my main program:

```
logging.getLogger("my_lib.my_func").level = logging.DEBUG
```

This works, however the messages aren't formatted as they would be if they had been handled by the Project logger.

In the main program, is there a way to "link" or forward logging messages from the `my_lib.my_func` logger to the Project logger to take advantage of the formatting provided by the Project logger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the handlers/formatters which are currently added to the project logger to the root logger, then you will get all logging using them, including the logging from `my_Lib.my_func`. Otherwise, you will have to duplicate the same set up as the project logger has for the `my_lib` logger (or the `my_lib.my_func` logger).

Comment: Pretty-much what I expected.  Works as advertised.  Just in case no one has thanked you today for your work on the Logging module, "Thanks Vinay."